# How do I spy on a controller method using Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using the "controller as" syntax to create my controller. I have a private initialization function that calls a function to load the default data.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var mc = this;
  mc.dataLoaded = false;

  function init() {
    mc.loadData();
  }

  mc.loadData = function(){
    mc.dataLoaded = true;
  }

  init();
});
```

In my test I'm creating a spy to check whether the `loadData` function has been called. Although I can verify that the function has been called by testing for the `mc.dataLoaded` flag, my spy doesn't seem to record the function being called. How can I get the spy to correctly record the function call?

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl as mc', {
      $scope: $scope
    });

    spyOn($scope.mc, 'loadData').and.callThrough();
  }));

  it('should call load data', function() {
    expect($scope.mc.loadData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  //expect($scope.mc.dataLoaded).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/05VDJ5Vvb0z8PdI0Hr77?p=preview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sequence of lines:

```
ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl as mc', {
  $scope: $scope
});

spyOn($scope.mc, 'loadData').and.callThrough();
```

Means that the Jasmine spy is created *after* the controller has already been instantiated by $controller. Before the spy is created, the `init` function has already executed.

You can't switch the lines around either, because MainCtrl needs to exist before you can spy on a method on it.

If the `init` function calls another service, then spy on that service's method and assert that the service is called correctly. If MainCtrl is just doing something internally, then test the result of that, for example, by asserting that controller's data/properties are updated. It may not even be worth testing if it's trivial enough.

Also, since you're using the controller as syntax, you can reference the controller through the return value of calling $controller, rather than accessing the scope directly:

```
ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl as mc', {
  $scope: $scope
});

ctrl.loadData === $scope.mc.loadData; // true
```

Comment: Question maybe out of the scope... Could be possible to spyOn a function that is not in the $scope? I mean, spying `init` in that code.

Comment: " If MainCtrl is just doing something internally, then test the result of that, for example, by asserting that controller's data/properties are updated. It may not even be worth testing if it's trivial enough." THIS SHOULD BE BOLD!!!

Comment: And what the internal controller initialization code does not rely on another service, is complex enough to require testing, and has no side effects on scope properties? Is your only option to move the initialization code off into some other service? Seems like a shame to make your code more complicated just to enable unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that allowed me to avoid changing my controller. I included a `$state` mock service in the test suite's `beforeEach` method, and gave it a `reload` mock method:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    stateMock = {
        reload: function() {
            myCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl');
        }
    };
    ...
```

Then within the jasmine tests, I can simply call `stateMock.reload()` to re-initialize my controller while preserving my spies I declared in another `beforeEach` block.

Comment: Does that actually work? You're creating a new controller object so wouldn't the spies you had previously declared be thrown out with the old controller object?

Comment: Worked for my team. Verified by temporarily changing Jasmine tests to fail on unexpected values. Did it throw errors for you?